# why isn't the command redirect working (bash newbie)

Tags: bash, sh

the command (with the redirection):

```
 puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' default.pp --detailed-exitcodes || [ $? -eq 2 ] &> errorlog.txt
```

i'm know my way around bash but a redirection newbie (and I need the redirection to debug something)

the command outputs a lot of text to the screen but for some reason the error.txt file is empty.

I tried redirecting also like: `> errorlog.txt`and `..]> errorlog.txt` etc' but nothing seems to work.

The file is created but is empty

Comment: It's not clear what your attempting with  `|| [ $? -eq 2 ]]` followed by `&> errorlog.txt`. Why would you expect output from one side of an `||` to appear in redirection attached to the other side of that `||` ? Good luck.

Comment: I just copied this command from puppet output advising me to run this to get detailed errorlog. I don't really understand that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting the `[` command. Try this:

```
puppet apply --options... &> errorlog.txt
[ $? -eq 2 ] && do something
```